# How to format rspec 2 output with rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, rspec2, formatter

When I run rspec 2 with rails 3 I use

```
rake rspec
```

sometimes I'd like to use a different formatter, perhaps doc.

```
rake rspec --format doc
```

but unfortunately the option doesn't make it through to the rspec runner. How can I choose a different format when I run the command?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add default options to an .rspec file in the rails root folder. e.g.

```
--colour
--format documentation
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also skip rake and use the rspec command directly. In this case the --format option can be used to tell RSpec how to format the output, "documentation" (or "doc") and "progress" are valid options:

```
rspec spec --format doc
```

This is especially useful if you want to run a single test/spec file

```
rspec spec/models/your_model.rb --format doc
```